# Collating values based on constraints

Tags: matlab, merge

I have a matrix

```
       i     j    values
  a =  1     2    10
       1     2    20
       2     1    11
       2     2    10
       2     1     1
```

I want to merge rows for the matrix a based on the first two columns where the first two columns have same values. The result should look like

res =

```
 1     2    30
 2     1    12
 2     2    10
```

Is it possible to do this without loops?

Thanks

Comment: Check out `accumarray`

Comment: Thanks Dan! I didn't find that question before I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve unique pairs of the first two columns, then use the indices that map all of the rows in `a` to the unique pairs and finally accumulate according to the mapping the values in the third column:

```
[un, ~, subs] = unique(a(:,1:2),'rows');
[un accumarray(subs,a(:,3))]
```